# XQuery Delete all unnecessary nodes T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

Could you help me please with succh problem. I have an XML like:

```
<Root attr1="val1">
    <El1><Child1/></El1>
    <El2><Child2/></El2>
    ...
    <ElN><ChildN/></ElN>
</Root>
```

I need to delete with T-SQL all nodes but  node. So I don't know all nodes of the XML-documetn but if that docuemnt has  node I need to delete all other nodes but . So the result must be:

```
<Root attr1="val1">
    <El2><Child2/></El2>
</Root>
```

I thought about getting xml.query('(root/el2)[1]) to a new xml and then wrapping it with root element from the origin xml (somewhow). But if there is the way to modify origin xml?

Comment: Alas it's not valid XML, since the `<Child...>` elements are not closed, so you can't use the standard `query()`, `nodes()` and `value()` functions in SQL Server with it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your stated approach of creating a new document with just what you want to keep not viable? That'd be what I'd try first if I were in your position.

Comment: `set xml.modify('delete Root/*[not(self::El2)]')
where xml.exist('Root/El2') = 1`

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with XML where all of the elements are properly closed you could use the `query()` XML function to perform an XQuery like the following:

```sql
declare @xml xml = '<Root attr1="val1">
    <El1><Child1a/></El1>
    <El1><Child1b/></El1>
    <El2><Child2a/></El2>
    <El2><Child2b/></El2>
    <ElN><ChildNa/></ElN>
    <ElN><ChildNb/></ElN>
</Root>';

select @xml.query('
  for $root in /Root return
    <Root>
      {$root/@*}
      {$root/El2[1]}
    </Root>
');
```

This returns the XML output:

```xml
<Root attr1="val1"><El2><Child2a /></El2></Root>
```